# leaderboard.setScore not saving score in Phaser 3 plugin for Facebook Instant Games

Tags: facebook, phaser-framework, facebook-instant-games

I've started using the phaser3 plugin for facebook instant games. I'm trying to save the player score to a leaderboard but every time I reload the game the leaderboard shows no score entries.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
class Game extends Phaser.Scene{

constructor(){
    super({ key: 'Game', active: false });

}

create(){

    this.facebook.on('getleaderboard', function(leaderboard){
        this.leaderboard = leaderboard;

        console.log('leaderboard in preloader: ', this.leaderboard);
    }, this);

    this.facebook.getLeaderboard('leaderboard');
}

update(){
    if (this.game_over){
        this.leaderboard.setScore(this.score);
        return;
    }

}    
}
```

Let's asume `this.game_over` becomes true at some point, which it does. The leaderboard has been properly created in facebook developer portal and it's being properly retrieved (since I can see it in the console, even its components), just empty every single time.

I'm testing my game using the facebook embedded player by the way but can't see why that could be the problem.

I've followed [this](https://phaser.io/tutorials/facebook-instant-games-leaderboards/index) tutorial but had no success.

Has anyone faced a similar situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is this.score defined. It maybe undefined while setting score.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to clarify, this.score is not the problem either, I've even hardcoded an int there and still doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

Why you putting your function on UPDATE function? i think its wrong because update function will load every time.

Set a function when your life's over

```
setScore(score){
 ...facebook function
}
```

and call when you die, not on the UPDATE()